# Android Facebook SDK ShareDialog without link

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing a small project for university and want to implement some kind of Facebook sharing in my Android App (SDK >20).

The developer page of Facebook only lists possibilities for sharing links, photos and multimedia, but no option for just posting plain text.
As assumed, leaving the `.setContentUrl()` method in the following code unset or unused doesn't work.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
            .setContentDescription(
                    "\"Description"\"")
```

It just opens an empty share-Dialog.

I've already read about using a Sharing-Intent for this problem, but I want to make use of the Facebook SDK.

Comment: If you read you see it is not allowed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "ShareDialog" to show your content.

```
shareDialog.show(content);
```